# Four-legged Flying Animals

Tags: science-based, low-fantasy

Pegasus, griffins, dragons, sphinxes, hippogriffs... I think all of them
these fantastic creatures are very fascinating and challenging when it comes to explaining how they fly without relying on magic even though they have 6 limbs. I already know that evolutionarily it is almost, if not totally, impossible for such a creature to come into existence as all vertebrate life forms tend to have 4 limbs: 2 serving as wings and 2 serving as legs. But in my world, these creatures will arise artificially through magic, they are created beings, not evolved. So I would like to raise a question here.

**If these creatures arose from creation rather than evolution, could they still fly and (in the case of dragons, pegasi, griffins and hippogriffs) carry someone on their back?**

As recommended and even required by Stack Exchange (if I understand everything correctly), here are some details about my creatures that I believe will help generate more elaborate answers:

- They cannot rely too much on magic, if possible none at all;
- Must have 4 legs and 2 wings;
- They are able to fly and even carry someone on their backs;
- Their planet's atmosphere will be double that of our planet (ie more oxygen, more nitrogen, more argon, etc.) which, as far as I know, interferes with the organism of flying animals;
- And what their skeleton and musculature must be like.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "arose from creation"?

Comment: Creation magic. It's explained in the text.

Comment: However, even though they arise from magi, I don't want to give such a lame answer to explain the flight of these creatures as "it's magic". If I wanted an answer like that, I wouldn't even post all this text.

Answer (score 3):

### You can have six-limbed flyers, but only if they are small.

A six-limbed flyer is possible in theory, but they probably wouldn’t look like fantasy creatures exactly. There are a number of issues with the classic creature designs (some of which are unrelated to the number of limbs, such as long dragon tails.)

I’m not going to go into detail, but what I can say is that without magic, these creatures won’t be carrying anyone larger than a mouse. In fact, their size limit is smaller than a bird’s.

The largest flying animals in our world were azdarchid pterosaurs. Part of what allowed them to grow so large is The fact that they both launched and soared with the same set of limbs. Birds fly by jumping off the ground, and then flapping their wings. To do this, birds need powerful arms AND powerful legs. Once a bird is in the air, those powerful legs are dead weight.

Pterosaurs, on the other hand, jumped and flapped with the same limbs; their forelimbs. Because they launched from the ground with their wings, pterosaurs could afford to have light, weak back legs, making them better flyers.

Your fantasy animals will have it even worse than birds. They have not two, but four powerful limbs that do not contribute to flying once in the air. In addition, the forelimbs will interfere dramatically with aerodynamics. (On top of that, the wing muscles need to be rigged up in a sub-optimal way to get around the forelimbs.)

In addition, a six limbed animal would need a larger brain to control the extra muscles, but this increased brain size wouldn’t make it any smarter. The larger brain and extra muscles would mean a six limbed creature needs more food than a four-limbed creature of the same size. (Mind you, this specific issue isn’t a dealbreaker for all six limbed animals; in a dense jungle, a six-limbed creature might fare better than a monkey, due to having more hands to grab branches with. The extra limbs don’t really help a flying animal, though.)

Because of all these issues, these six-limbed two-winged flyers will be very restricted in size, barring magical interference. In fact, barring magical interference, these animals will struggle to compete with birds, and will likely go extinct.

Comment: extra limbs could be beneficial for hunting or other food acquisition but for flying yes they are a hinderance.